# Using variable in SetTimer function

Tags: variables, timer, automation, autohotkey, shutdown

I am trying to use this code with AutoHotkey but got the following error: SetTimer's second parameter is invalid.

Here is my code:

```
#Persistent
MyTime := 15 * 60
SetTimer, ShutdownNow, MyTime
return

ShutdownNow:
Shutdown, 1
return
```

I also tried:

```
MyTime = 15 * 60
SetTimer, ShutdownNow, %MyTime%
```

But I am still get the same error. What can be the problem?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this example and it works fine for me:

```
#Persistent
MyTime := 15 * 60
SetTimer, ShutdownNow, %MyTime%
return

ShutdownNow:
Shutdown, 1
return
```

I only replaced `SetTimer, ShutdownNow, MyTime` with `SetTimer, ShutdownNow, %MyTime%` .
If you tried and it does not work for you:

1. Use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ . *You should always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website)! AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems running scripts with it!*
2. Make sure you saved script before running it.
3. Run it with administrator privileges.

Comment: Thanks a lot vasili111, the code works now after your change.